# "No unprofiled JVMs found" on AIX Server - JProfiler

Tags: java, tomcat, aix, jprofiler

I am trying to run JProfiler so I can hook it up to a running Apache Tomcat running on an AIX server. I grabbed the tar ball for AIX and put it on the server, then extracted it. When I go to run jpenable in the bin directory, I get the following error:

```
No unprofiled JVMs found.

If the target JVM is running as a different user, restart as 
    sudo -u [user] jpenable
```

I thought it might have just been something with the environment, so just to be safe I also tried to run it with the command line flags to get it to launch:

```
jpenable --pid=5505272 --gui --port=1234
```

However that gave me the following error:

```
No JVM with PID 5505272 found that is running as the same user.

If the target JVM is running as a different user, restart as
sudo -u [user] jpenable
```

I did a `ps -ef | grep tomcat` and verified that it is indeed running as root, and I am logged in as root, but JProfiler still cannot find the running JVM.

---

From the JProfiler Manual: `This only works with a Java VM of version 1.6 or higher`. Once I saw that, I verified my java version and the version that tomcat is running under is 1.8, so that shouldn't be an issue?

Anyone have any ideas as to why it won't connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of JProfiler 10.0, the attach feature only works with HotSpot JVMs and not with IBM J9 JVMs.

Comment: Indeed, you need to add the "-agentpath" VM parameter for profiling to the start script.